# htaccess document_root dirname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, document-root, dirname

is it possible to do this

```
RewriteRule robots.txt dirname(%{DOCUMENT_ROOT})/robots.php [L]
```

i need get parent folder of DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: Is this in a .htaccess file or in httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a rewrite rule pointing to a target outside the document root in the context of a `.htaccess` file, so even if it were possible to find out the parent directory (which I doubt), it won't work.

The only way around this that I know is creating a symbolic link that points to the correct `robots.php` file. It may even be possible to create a relative symbolic link pointing to `../robots.php`, I'm not sure.

Comment: but why in php i can write dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) and get access to files upside the current folder?

Comment: @kusanagi This is a rule set up by Apache that applies only to `RewriteRule` and `Alias` instructions in .htaccess files, for security reasons. PHP runs completely separately from all this, and doesn't have this specific restriction.

Comment: so in htaccess i can't get any access to parent folder? only throuhg php?

Comment: @kusanagi yup, exactly - or alternatively, by editing the central configuration. There are no such limitations in the httpd.conf file

Comment: ok, but why this code is working-RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/robots.txt !-f it cheking parent file robots.txt

Comment: @kusanagi that target is *inside* the document root, isn't it?